# File Format and Extension does not match in Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, xlsx, xls

Exporting MySQL Data to Excel File using the below code:

```
$i = 0;
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $rowData = '';  
    foreach ($row as $value) {  
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";  
        $rowData .= $value;  
    }  
    $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";
            $i++;

        }
$filename = $i." numbers ".date('d m Y') . ".xls";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Expires: 0");
    echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";
```

It successfully exports the file and also opens correctly but there is a dialogue box before it file is opened.

[image: Dialogue Box]

When I use the extension as `xlsx`, the file is not opening and gives a dialogue box:

[image: Dialogue Box 2]

Why it is coming and how to remove it?

Comment: Providing none of your values contain double-quote characters " you could change the tab delimiter to comma and the file extension to ".csv" the format it is. .xls and .xlsx files are binary not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong delimiters for a row use \r\n instead

```
    $i = 0;
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $rowData = '';  
        foreach ($row as $value) {  
             $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";  
             $rowData .= $value;  
        }  
     $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\r\n";
     $i++;

    }
```

If you want you can try

> implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";

to get your complete rowData to add to setData, php ha sa lot of functions to explore

like [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)  and  [array_value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

anther think is , that you should add a header line  before using the result of your select.

Comment: but the dialogue box still there.

Comment: Please Post a sample of your received file and don't use spaces in your filenames.

Comment: I see the probolem xls is a binary format. xslx is as xml based format, but you have a csv file. so change the ending to csv and at least it opens the file, but still he doesn't like the tabs as seperator, this you can use only when you umport it. when you build a text file, always take a look in a texteditor like pspad or notpad++ to see what you generated.